# Can I change game center achievement's image?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, game-center

Hi I wanted to know if I can change the images at any time later? I'm rushed to submit my game and can't wait till the images are finished so I'm using the game's icon for all achievements now, can I change them later after the app is live on appstore or while the app is waiting for review?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I've found that the short answer for this question is yes we can change the images at anytime. I've tried it on a previously approved app and it's worked fine.